# Why did my DDR3 memory VSS pin burn?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

I have an ASUS P9X79 motherboard. It had one 8GB DDR3 1600MHz memory module installed. I wanted to use some slower 1333MHz Muskin memory I had with it (https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226095). This machine was quite dusty inside and I gave it a blast of compressed air, though that made a decent cloud.

At first the machine booted and reported 12GB of memory. I shutdown and moved the new memory around and ultimately ended with both memory modules' VSS pins visibly damaged - the smell caught my attention first:

[image: VSS pins burned]

Since the memory worked at all, I'm wagering the issue was actually dust. Is there some DDR3 pitfall I've stumbled in to here? I wonder if it was just dust, I might actually be able to repair these modules as the burn might have been too must resistance that only burned the PCB itself.

Comment: Have you tried wiping them down to see if it's residue from burnt dust or it's the gold itself that's gone. (Alcohol won't dissolve the gold).
As long as you have metal still on the pin it should work. The point of the gold is for it do form to the contact to ensure stable connection but as long as there is still metal there it's not unlikely it will work without issues.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, one has more metal left than the other. I have isopropyl and am a bit experienced with conducting board-level repairs, so I'm comfortable to goof with it. I hope the burning smell they both made was just the PCBs burning, but everything's actually fine. It kind of makes sense that it could be fine, if the issue was dust cranking-up the resistance at that location.